# How do I get a simple deform modifier to twist from the bottom of the object instead of the middle?

Tags: animation, modifiers

I'm trying to copy this animation I found online (first image) using blender 2.83. I'm using a combination of a shape key (to squash the cube), a simple deform modifier (to twist), and finally keyframing the cube for rotation. My issue is the deform modifier twists the entire cube - in the original animation the base stays locked. How might I go about this? Any suggestions would be greatly welcome. Thanks

PS - I also tried twisting the cube using a shape key but the end result would intersect itself and looked ugly.

[This is my Blender File](https://pasteall.org/blend/66ab675d0eef4498949d16df3ecd040d)

[image: Text]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just have to slide your controlling empty 1 unit down.

[image]

Comment: exactly, except it goes in the other direction at the end, the cube does something like frame 30 = 0°, frame 45 = 360° (instead of -180)

Comment: Yes! Huge thanks. I'm pretty new to Blender and was racking my mind for hours trying different approaches unsuccessfully. Sending good vibes your way.